# How to prove general formula for expected value for discrete random variable

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, expected-value

This general formula for expected value is used everywhere for the proofs regarding expected value for discrete variable but I could not see the proof for it anywhere.

If $(\Omega, P)$ is finite probability room and X be a random variable in $\Omega$

$E(X) = \sum\limits_{y \in X(\Omega)}(y.P(X=y)) $

How do I prove this mathematically?

It shows that the expected value can be calculated without explicitly mentioning $\Omega$, which I think is very helpful but how do I first prove this general formula?

The textbook I am using defines the expected value [image: like this]. This basically looks the same as this question, but one of the exercises is to prove this question.

Comment: What is your definition of expected value ?

Comment: @StratosFair Do you mean to say, this in itself is a definition of expected value and doesn't need proof?

Comment: Perhaps this is the definition.  Or, if your textbook has another definition, then you need to use that definition to answer the question.

Comment: @BlueMango I mean that it depends on the lecture notes/textbook you use. Some people may define the expectation of a discrete r.v. this way, in which case there is nothing to prove. If you're working with another, more general definition of expected value then it is possible to prove the identity based on that definition, but we need to know what that definition is.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the textbook definition of the expected value

Comment: It may be best to give full references, which is the textbook, which is the definition of a probability space (if any, since lazy German courses are performing a probability quick+light show in order to step into the matter in time), and if we have a definition - what should be shown? Note that as a matter of **notation** the expression $P(X=a)$ stays for $P(\ \{a\}\ )$ in case of a discrete probability space.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the LOTUS-Principle (Law Of The Unconscious Statistician). Let $(\Omega, \mathbb P)$ a discrete probability space (that means $\Omega$ is countable) and $X(\Omega)$ is a countable set, the set of all images of the function $X$.

We need to prove the following:
$$\mathbb E(X):=\sum_{\omega\in\Omega}X(\omega)\cdot\mathbb P(\omega)
=\sum_{k\in X(\Omega)}k\cdot\mathbb P(\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)=k\})=\sum_{k\in X(\Omega)}k\cdot\mathbb P(X=k).$$

There is actually not much to prove, it is only understanding what is going on.

More generally, we also have by the same type of argument for measurable function $f$
$$\mathbb E(f(X))=\sum_{k\in X(\Omega)}f(k)\cdot\mathbb P(X=k).$$

Answer (score 0):

Group the $a$'s by the value of $X(a)$ and note

$$\mathbb{P}(X=y) = \sum_{a\in \Omega \\ X(a)=y} \mathbb{P}(\{a\}).$$